# Using a Java library with Scala reserved words

Tags: java, scala, selenium, scala-java-interop

I'm using an external library written in Java ([Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29)). One of the function calls has the signature `type(String, String)`, and I keep getting compiler errors when trying to call it from Scala, that is:

```
selenium.type("ab","abc")
```

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
selenium.`type`("ab","abc")
```

Comment: Thanks, just started doing scala and didn't know the use of that little ` symbol.