# How do I call a Java method named the same as a Scala keyword?

Tags: java, scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Java Lib with Scala Reserved Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793984/using-java-lib-with-scala-reserved-words)

I'm experimenting with Scala, and a Java library I'm using has a `with` method on one of its objects, but `with` is a keyword in Scala. How do I call this method from my Scala code?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576594/need-clarification-on-scala-literal-identifiers-backticks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/TypeLessDoMore.html#ReservedWords

> Some Java methods use names that are reserved by Scala, e.g., java.util.Scanner.match. To avoid a compilation error, surround the name with single back quotes, e.g., java.util.Scanner.‵match‵.

(edited for formatting)

Comment: Despite the closure, thanks for this response.