# Using @RelatedTo with Spring Data Neo4j and Scala - annotation arg is Scala reserved word

Tags: scala, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Spring Data for Neo4j with Scala and have the following dilemma.  I'm trying to use the @RelatedTo annotation as specified:

**@RelatedTo(type = "in")
  var state: String = _**

but of course this doesn't compile because *type* is a Scala reserved word.

Are there any workarounds or do I just have to write a Scala wrapper for @RelatedTo with a different parameter name or something similar?

Thanks!
Steve Nester

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know anything about those libraries/frameworks, but you should be able to use backticks. Try this:

```
@RelatedTo(`type` = "in") var state: String = _
```

See also [Using a Java library with Scala reserved words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793984/using-a-java-library-with-scala-reserved-words)